# ngAnimate working on ng-leave but not ng-enter

Tags: html, css, angularjs, animation, ng-animate

Consider the following CSS:

```
nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1900;
  top:0; right:0; bottom:0;
  width: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: right 600ms cubic-bezier(.3,1,.5,1);
  -moz-transition: right 600ms cubic-bezier(.3,1,.5,1);
  -o-transition: right 600ms cubic-bezier(.3,1,.5,1);
  transition: right 600ms cubic-bezier(.3,1,.5,1); }

nav.ng-enter { right: -60px; }
nav.ng-enter.ng-enter-active { right: 0; }

nav.ng-leave { right: 0; }
nav.ng-leave.ng-leave-active { right: -60px; }
```

Then of course I have ng-if attribute on the nav in the HTML:

```
<nav ng-if="account.isLoggedIn && navIsOpen">
  ...
</nav>
```

The animation works fine on ng-leave. I can also see in developer tools that the ng-enter and ng-enter-active classes are added for the correct transition duration, but instead of the transition happening, the element just appears in place. Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you give us a fiddle? From the look of what you provided, it seems to me like it should be working. Also, what version of ngAnimate are you using? 1.3 has fixed a lot of weird animation bugs that showed up in 1.2.

Comment: @Semicolon yes an update from 1.2 to v1.3 fixed it! Thanks, I didn't even realise I was on a legacy version.

Comment: I think 1.2 is still considered the stable release, but I've been using the 1.3 release candidate without problems. It addresses other animation issues, too -- for example show/hide and enter/exit animations finally work properly for elements where display != block.